# Display only part of a kml file in Google maps api for Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on an application that uses a public api for a local transit system. Part of this app involves drawing the path of a specific bus route on a Map using the maps api.

It's easy enough to add a kml layer to the map like so:

```
    KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(map, resId, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    layer.addLayerToMap();
```

The *problem* is, I'm given the kml data for ~100 routes in one large file.

Here's a *very* small sample of what the file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
  <Placemark>
      <ExtendedData>
        <Data name="route_number">
          <value>67</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="direction">
          <value>0</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="route_description">
          <value>Bethany/158th</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="public_route_number">
          <value>67</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="direction_description">
          <value>To PCC Rock Creek</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="frequent">
          <value>False</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="type">
          <value>BUS</value>
        </Data>
      </ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry>
        <LineString>
          <coordinates>-122.858564,45.566031 -122.858623,45.566074 -122.858682,45.566096 -122.858754,45.566103 -122.858829,45.566096 -122.859393,45.565952</coordinates>
        </LineString>
        <LineString>
          <coordinates>-122.859215,45.563005 -122.859429,45.563006 -122.859430,45.563086 -122.859418,45.563214 -122.859404,45.563267 </coordinates>
        </LineString>
      </MultiGeometry>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <ExtendedData>
        <Data name="route_number">
          <value>67</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="direction">
          <value>1</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="route_description">
          <value>Bethany/158th</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="public_route_number">
          <value>67</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="direction_description">
          <value>To Merlo Rd/158th Ave</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="frequent">
          <value>False</value>
        </Data>
        <Data name="type">
          <value>BUS</value>
        </Data>
      </ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry>
        <LineString>
          <coordinates>-122.859393,45.565952 -122.859394,45.565951 -122.859515,45.565912 -122.859605,45.565868 -122.859664,45.565818 -122.859721,45.565759 -122.859753,45.565709 -122.859786,45.565640 -122.859814,45.565569 -122.859710,45.565552 -122.859617,45.565533 </coordinates>
        </LineString>
      </MultiGeometry>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Essentially, each route is a different placemark within the kml file. I'd like to access only one placemark at a time by the route number.

I'm not sure how I'd go about extracting only one placemark from the kml file and displaying it on the map.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'd like to access only one placemark at a time by the route number.**

Reading through the KML Android Docs, it mentions how to Access [KML placemarks](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml#containers).

Code snippet:

```
for (KmlPlacemark placemark : layer.getPlacemarks()) {
  // Do something to Placemark
}
```

To access any property in a container or placemark, call getProperty() and give it a property key. You can also call hasProperty() to check if it exists. This sample shows how to retrieve the property value "name" from a container, if it exists.

```
for (KmlContainer container : layer.getContainers()) {
  if (container.hasProperty("name")) {
    System.out.println(container.getProperty("name")):
  }
}
```

You can also try to make use of [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) to parse KML and access the individual objects. For more info, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347309/display-kml-file-on-a-map).